# How to show the names of non-participants in the last sending quiz in each division?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing an intranet web application that provides the users with short quizzes. The quizzes will be sent to the users via emails. I have the following database design:

> Employee Table: Username, Name, Job, DivisionID
>
> Division Table: DivisionID, DivisionName
>
> Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description, IsSent
>
> UserQuiz Table: UserQuizID, Score, DateTimeComplete, QuizID, Username

***NOTE: The first attribute in each table is the primary key.***

And for your information, IsSent is a flag used to determine which quiz is sent to the users and which one is not.

**What I want and need now is:** I need to come up with a query that shows the names of the non-participants in the last sending quiz. It means if there is more than one quiz that is sent to the users, this query should display the names of non-participants in the last sending quiz. The query also should display the DivisionName, too.

I came up with the following query but it shows the non-participants in all quizzes in the database. So how to modify it? or how to get what is required above?

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Q.Title, D.DivisionShortcut, E.Name
FROM         dbo.Quiz AS Q CROSS JOIN
                      dbo.employee AS E LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions AS D ON E.DivisionCode = D.SapCode
WHERE     (NOT EXISTS
                          (SELECT     UserQuizID, QuizID, DateTimeComplete, Score, Username
                            FROM          dbo.UserQuiz AS UQ
                            WHERE      (Username = E.Username) AND (QuizID = Q.QuizID)))
ORDER BY Q.Title, D.DivisionShortcut
```

Comment: How do you know which quiz has been sent last?

Comment: How do you define "last sending quiz"?  The Quiz table has no DateTimeSent field?  Do you go off of the DateTimeComplete in UserQuiz table?  Thus, you're only looking to get this information for that most recently *completed* quiz?

Comment: From the IsSent attribute in the Quiz table as mentioned above. Each week there is a quiz will be sent automatically by the system to all users. When the quiz is sent, IsSent value will be 1. My query above is not complete and this is what I am asking about.

Comment: Is this something still in development?  Really what I'm asking is, are you able to modify your DB Design at all?  You don't currently have a way to sort the last sent quiz, only the last completed quiz.  If there are 3 quizes, all sent to your users, and all with isSent=1, you can't sort that.  What would be more helpful is to replace isSent with a DateTime signifying when the quiz was sent, or when the quiz *will be* sent.  Either way, this will give you proper sorting ability and still represent the data you get with isSent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last quiz sent is

```
select max(quizID) from dbo.Quiz where IsSent = 1
```

users that participated at last quiz:

```
select A.QuizID, a.Username 
from UserQuiz a join 
 (select max(quizID) quizID from dbo.Quiz where IsSent = 1) b
  on a.QuizId = b.quizID
```

users that did not participate at the last quiz

```
select u.name, d.DivisionName
from
  users u
  join Divisions d on (u.divisionID = d.divisionID)
  left join 
    (select A.QuizID, a.Username 
     from UserQuiz a join 
     (select max(quizID) quizID from dbo.Quiz where IsSent = 1) b
     on a.QuizId = b.quizID
     ) c
   on u.username = c.username
 where c.QuizID is null
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. But could you please explain to me the last line in the query (where c.QuizID is null)?

Comment: Ok, please observe the `left join`. it tries to match every user in the table users with every user from table c (that is, user that participated at last quiz). If a user from table users don't have a match in table c, then columns c.quizID, c.username will be nulls. These users are those who didn't participated at quiz.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a correlated subquery (that is executed for *every* row, and is therefore a poorly performing query), I would express it using a `NOT IN`, and simplify the whole thing, like this:

```
SELECT Q.Title, D.DivisionShortcut, E.Name
FROM (
    SELECT Title, QuizID
    FROM UserQuiz
    WHERE QuizID = (SELECT MAX(QuizID) FROM UserQuiz)) Q
CROSS JOIN employee E
JOIN Divisions D ON E.DivisionCode = D.SapCode
WHERE E.Username NOT IN (
    SELECT Username
    FROM UserQuiz
    WHERE QuizID = Q.QuizID)
ORDER BY Q.Title, D.DivisionShortcut
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but your query does work. What I tried to use it, I got the following error: Invalid column name 'Title'. (in the third line of your query)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select q.Title, d.DivisionShortcut, e.Name
from (select top 1 * from Quiz where IsSent = 1 order by QuizID desc) q
cross join Employee e
join Division d on e.divisionID = d.divisionID
where not exists
(select null from UserQuiz uq
 where uq.QuizID = q.QuizID and uq.Username = e.Username)
```